# Modify existing inline code for asp.net in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have an item template inside a gridview which is an a:href and whose value depends on a bound field inside the same grid view. So, if the value of the bound field(testType) is 1, there will be one link and if it is 2, it will display another link. Here is the code:

```
         <ItemTemplate>
             <%#
                 Int32.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "testType").ToString()) == 1 ?
                "<a target=\"_self\" href=\"TestRequestOverview.aspx?testCaseId=" + Int32.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "testCaseId").ToString()) + "&toggle=1" + "&mode=toggle\" class=\"myToggle\">Change to Performance Test</a>" :

                "<a target=\"_self\" href=\"TestRequestOverview.aspx?testCaseId=" + Int32.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "testCaseId").ToString()) + "&toggle=1" + "&mode=toggle\" class=\"myToggle\">Change to Unit Test</a>"
             %>

            </ItemTemplate>
```

Now the requirement has changed and I have to add a third condition to check if the testType is 0, so I can't use the ternary operator. I'm not very familiar with the asp inline code syntax and wondering how to use may be if-else block and still access the field using Container.DataItem, can someone help me please please please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the markup for each is very similar, I'd use a simple lookup object:

```
<script runat="server">
    private Dictionary<int, string> TypeNames = new  Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 1, "Change to Performance Test" },
        { 2, "Change to Unit Test" },
        // etc
    };
</script>

<ItemTemplate>
    <a target="_self" 
        href="TestRequestOverview.aspx?testCaseId=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "testType") %>&mode=toggle"
        class="myToggle">
        <%# TypeNames[Int32.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "testType").ToString())] %>
    </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```